# Java recursive method to print one word in a string at a time without loops

Tags: java, string, recursion

For this program, the idea is to print one word in a string at a time using a recursive method, assuming that there is only one word between spaces. When I run this program as is, however, it instead prints the string itself.

```
public static void stringByWords(String s) {


    if (s.isEmpty())

        return;

    if (s.indexOf(" ") == 1)

     stringByWords(s.substring(s.indexOf(" ") + 1) + "\n");

    System.out.println(s);


}//end stringByWords
```

I realize it would be a hell of a lot easier to do this as an iterative method with just a loop, but I'm required to use recursion as instructed. Any tips as to what I'm doing incorrectly will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The trick with recursion is to follow the standard pattern

```
func(context)
    if context is very simple
        process context
    else
        break context into several pieces
            call func on each piece
```

So for your case, the simple situation is a single words with no spaces. Otherwise break into two pieces and call on each piece:

```
void printWords(String str) {
    int space = str.indexOf(' ');
    if (space == -1) {
        System.out.println(str);
    } else {
        printWords(str.substring(0, space));
        printWords(str.substring(space + 1));
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, I see. I forgot that I would need to update the string, error on my part. And thank you for the tip about recursion, that actually does help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, after fixing up my code from the tips I was given, it seems to function as intended. I will put the fixed code here in case it is helpful to someone else. Thanks to those who had helped.

```
public static void stringByWords(String s) {

    int space = s.indexOf(' ');

    if (s.isEmpty()) //error case

        return;

    if (space == -1) { //base case

        System.out.println(s);
    }
    else { 

        stringByWords(s.substring(0, space));//recursive steps
        stringByWords(s.substring(space + 1));

    }//end else


}//end stringByWords
```